# Can I grep for 2 patterns and have them listed side by side?

Tags: grep, json

Ubuntu 16.04

```
bash -version  
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

I would like to `grep` for 2 patterns and then have them listed side by side. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
root@tires ~ # grep -e tire_id -e appID /path/to/*/vehicle/production.json
/path/to/000001_000002/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "1305436516186552",
/path/to/000001_000002/vehicle/production.json:        "appID": "1164562920689523",
/path/to/000001_000079/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "1815123428733289",
/path/to/000001_000079/vehicle/production.json:        "appID": "18412365908966538",
/path/to/000001_000088/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "138477888324",
```

This is what I would like to have although anything similar would work actually.

```
root@tires ~ # grep -e tire_id -e appID /path/to/*/vehicle/production.json
/path/to/000001_000002/vehicle/production.json:    tire_id: 1305436516186552, appID: 1164562920689523
/path/to/000001_000079/vehicle/production.json:    tire_id: 1815123428733289, appID: 18412365908966538
```

File example here:

```
{
    "socal": "https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx",
    "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "tire_id": "213275925375485",
    "client": {
        "platform": "xx",
        "clientID": "xxxxx",
        "serviceID": "xxxxx",
        "service_id": XXXX,
        "vendor": "default"
    },
    "locale": "en_US",
    "cdc": {
        "appID": "233262274090443",
        "isdel": "ORdiZBMAQS2ZBCnTwZDZD",
    },
    "attachments": {
        "output": "attachments",
        "public": false,
    },
}
```

Comment: Looks like something more apt for `jq` than `grep`.

Comment: post a testable `production.json` contents

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I posted an example, see OP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The right way with **`jq`** tool for a valid JSON documents:

Sample `file1.json`:

```
{
    "socal": "https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx",
    "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "tire_id": "213275925375485",
    "client": {
        "platform": "xx",
        "clientID": "xxxxx",
        "serviceID": "xxxxx",
        "service_id": "XXXX",
        "vendor": "default"
    },
    "locale": "en_US",
    "cdc": {
        "appID": "233262274090443",
        "isdel": "ORdiZBMAQS2ZBCnTwZDZD"
    },
    "attachments": {
        "output": "attachments",
        "public": false
    }
}
```

---

Sample `file2.json`:

```
{
    "socal": "https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx",
    "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "tire_id": "1305436516186552",
    "client": {
        "platform": "xx",
        "clientID": "xxxxx",
        "serviceID": "xxxxx",
        "service_id": "XXXX",
        "vendor": "default"
    },
    "locale": "en_US",
    "cdc": {
        "appID": "1164562920689523",
        "isdel": "ORdiZBMAQS2ZBCnTwZDZD"
    },
    "attachments": {
        "output": "attachments",
        "public": false
    }
}
```

---

And the solution itself:

```
jq -r 'input_filename + " tire_id: \(.tire_id) appID: \(.cdc.appID)"' file*.json
```

The output:

```
file1.json tire_id: 213275925375485 appID: 233262274090443
file2.json tire_id: 1305436516186552 appID: 1164562920689523
```

Comment: Your answer is much simpler and efficient for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `grep` but it's rather conplicated and Roman's answer is actually better.

Your example contents are just from one file so there is only once instance of `tire_id` and `appID`.

Use this:

```
echo $(echo /path/to/production.json && egrep "tire_id|appID" /path/to/production.json | sed -e 's|"||g' | sed -e 's|,||2') && echo $(echo /path/to/production2.json && egrep "tire_id|appID" /path/to/production2.json ) | sed -e 's|"||g' | sed -e 's|,||2'
```

`echo` puts everything on the same line with command substitution.

`egrep` does the same thing as `grep -e` but allows you to put all the strings together separated by `|` instead of having to use `-e string` each time.

`sed -e 's|"||g'` removes the apostrophes.

`sed -e 's|,||2` removes the comma from the end of the value for `appID` which is what is shown in your desired output.

Output:

```
/path/to/production.json tire_id: 213275925375485 appID: 233262274090443
/path/to/production2.json tire_id: 1815123428733289 appID: 18412365908966538
```

`/path/to/production.json` and `/path/to/production2.json` are just placeholders.

This obviously requires a lot of modification as you'd have to grep each file separately and use an `echo` command substitution for each one. I'm only including it if you insist upon using `grep` or if in the future, it's not a `json` file.

Comment: @Your answer is awesome and I learned a lot from it. Much appreciated. You are also right about Roman's answer.  He uses the command made for the job, which I did not know existed. Hat's off to you mate.

Comment: @needtoknow No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

With a sed script :

```
grep -e tire_id -e appID /path/to/*/vehicle/production.json | sed -n '/\(.*:\)/h;n;s/.*n://;H;g;s/\n//;p'
```

Retrun

```
/path/to/000001_000002/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "1305436516186552",        "appID": "1164562920689523",
/path/to/000001_000079/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "1815123428733289",        "appID": "18412365908966538",
/path/to/000001_000088/vehicle/production.json:    "tire_id": "138477888324",
```

it works if each line "tire_id" is followed by a line "appID".
Otherwise, you need a more complex sed script

Comment: This is also nice. Can you remove the apostrophes and commas.

Comment: sed -n 'h;n;s/.*n://;H;g;s/\n//;s/"//g;s/,//g;p'

Answer (score 0):

This command will work even if in a file it misses a "tire_id" or "appID" line. It will not be displayed :

```
grep -e tire_id -e appID /path/to/*/vehicle/production.json | sed -n 's/\(tire_id\)/\1/;T;h;n;s/.*n:.*\(appID\)/\1/;T;H;g;s/\n/ /;s/"//g;s/,//g;p'
```

Comment: Very cool mate. I learned a lot from it.